# Is this bike XC or Trail?

Tags: mountain-bike, xc

My bike is a Exitway R16 with Rockshox Recon suspension. I was wondering if is this bike for XC racing, light trail riding or both. The bike is not the fastest nor the slowest, I have a little hard time doing bunny hops.

Comment: Note for close voters: trail and xc are fairly established categories of bikes.

Comment: A slightly facetious comment but does it matter? There's quite a gradual crossover between the two and either will generally handle the other fairly well. You already have to bike to just ride it and see how it gets on with the rides you want to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your bike is an entry level hardtail MTB with quality components. I just did a quick google search and looked at few pictures of the bike. It looks like it isn't specifically XC or Trail bike, it's more like an **all round MTB**.

It will work for both XC racing and light trails, every XC-Bike is suitable for light trails, just look at the more technical sections of the track in XC-races.

Your bike is just as good for bunny hopping as any other MTB, bunny hops are more about the right technique then about the bike you use. Keep practising.